# Potential security hazards of this network topology

Tags: security, routing, switch, high-availability, sonicwall

Long story short, we just implemented HA with 2 sonicwall nsa3600s... we only have 1 ISP connection on site... therefore we need a switch on the WAN side to split the connection off to both WAN interfaces on the primary and secondary sonicwalls.

PROBLEM IS, we don't have any available switches! My boss is hell bent on getting this configured, however, he's suggesting that I configure a vlan on our internal LAN switch stack, and use that to segment out 3 ports to use for this purpose.

SO- the proposed topology is that the ISP comes into it's own vlan on a port on our LAN SWITCHSTACK, then splits off back to the WAN interfaces on the sonicwalls, then back down to the switchstack through the sonicwalls LAN interface.

Needless to say, I think this is a horrible idea. But, I don't have any hard facts as to WHY its a terrible idea, other than.... THE LAN APPLIANCES SHOULD ALWAYS STAY BEHIND THE FIREWALL.... Can anybody tell me the potential hazards and security holes this creates? He claims this was how it was set up at his last job....

Some potential inconsistencies that come to mind are the fact that vlans are a layer 2 technology while data will be routing through these switchports... what about broadcast storms and ddos attacks? I don't know... it just seems really, really wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What your boss proposes will work fine with no security issues.

**EXCEPT**, that a misconfiguration on your internal switch could inadvertently bridge untrusted traffic to inside your firewall.

And considering the most common source of network problems is accidental misconfiguration, this is a real risk. Be sure to document things well.

Of course, your boss will probably respond that correct switch configurations are entirely your responsibility.  You'll have to deal with that.

Your other objections are baseless.  There is no "inconsistency" problem.  Any external DoS or storm will saturate the WAN link long before it will affect the switch.